# How to print week number of previous week in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, unix

Can anyone please help me to get the previous week number ?

I tried following before askign this here.

This one works but not able to couple it with year number.

```
echo `date +%W `-1 | bc``
2
```

Here are the failures I am getting while coupling year and previous week number

```
echo `date +%Y`wk`date +%W `-1 | bc``
(standard_in) 1: parse error

echo "`date +%Y`wk`date +%W `-1 | bc``"
2016wk03-1 | bc
```

## Outupt desired :

CUrrentYEARwkPREVIOUSWEEK

like

```
2016wk02
```

**Note: I am trying to get this done using oneliner , trying to avoide use of variable here.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `-d 'last week'` option and avoid `bc` etc:

```
date -d 'last week' '+%Ywk%W'
2016wk02
```